# CYGWIN error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: gcc, mono, cygwin, mingw

I try to compile mono using cygwin([manual](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_on_Windows)), but I get the following output:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/a/TempForCompile/mono-master':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Some parts of [config.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4jsXYhk52gaUVptMldkNk9oY0k/edit?usp=sharing):

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
```

How to fix this issue and compile mono?

Comment: Did you get the latest cygwin version? Did you get the 32-bit build? Did you get the latest versions of these packages: gcc-core, gcc-g++, mingw-gcc*?

Comment: @ooga I downloaded cygwin installer from [official site](http://cygwin.com/install.html), launched it and chose "Install from Internet", so I think that I have the latest version of cygwin.
I have 64-bit version of Windows, so I downloaded `setup-x86_64.exe`(but I think I didn't understand your question right).
I installed this packages using same cygwin installer: I mark these packages for install and after that I checked them using `cygcheck`. All other packages that I installed were found, but packages with a hyphen in the name were not found(If I using `cygcheck mingw-gcc`).

Comment: @user2656632 You should try using cygwin's 32-bit version instead of 64-bit version